# Pandas: Get N largest values and insert NaN values if there are no elements

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Farmer': ['John', 'Nick', 'Jane',  'Jane', 'John',  'Jane', 'John', 'Nick'],
                       'Animal': ['Cow', 'Sheep', 'Dolphin', 'Sheep', 'Horse',  'Dinosaur', 'Pig', 'Horse'],
                       'Weight': [200, 50 , 90 , 56, 180, 160, 150, 175]})
```

```
        Farmer  Animal  Weight
    0   John    Cow      200
    1   Nick    Sheep    50
    2   Jane    Dolphin  90
    3   Jane    Sheep    56
    4   John    Horse    180
    5   Jane    Dinosaur 160
    6   John    Pig      150
    7   Nick    Horse    175
```

And I want to group dataframe by the `'Farmer'` column then to get the weights of 3 largest animals for each farmer as 3 columns.

```
        Farmer  top1_animal_weight top2_animal_weight top3_animal_weight
    0   John       200                   180               150          
    1   Nick       175                    50               NaN 
    2   Jane       160                    90               56
```

Firstly, I tried to apply `nlargest` method to each group but it doesn't return `NaN` when there is no 3rd largest element. And also I don't know how to transform one weigth column to three

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create the columns with `rank` then `pivot`

```
out = df.assign(Rank=df.groupby('Farmer')['Weight'].rank(ascending=False)).pivot(index='Farmer', columns='Rank',values='Weight')
Out[202]: 
Rank      1.0    2.0    3.0
Farmer                     
Jane    160.0   90.0   56.0
John    200.0  180.0  150.0
Nick    175.0   50.0    NaN
```

Comment: Essentially you are pivoting a grouped dataframe right? Beautiful answer.