# How to get second highest value in a pandas column for a certain ID?

Tags: python, pandas

So I think this question can be visualized the best as following, given a dataframe:

```
val_1          true_val ID      label
-0.0127894447       0.0  1       A
0.9604560385        1.0  2       A
0.0001271985        0.0  3       A
0.0007419337        0.0  3       B
0.3420448566        0.0  2       B
0.1322384726        1.0  4       B
```

So what I want to get is:

```
label  ID_val_1_second_highest    ID_true_val_highest
A        3                              2
B        4                              4
```

I want to get the ID that has the second highest value for val_1 and highest value for true_val (which is always the one with 1.0) and then return both corresponding ID's for every label.

Anyone have an idea how to do this? I tried:

> result_at_one = result.set_index('ID').groupby('label').idxmax()

This works for giving me the highest value for both, but I only want the highest value for the true label while getting the second / third etc. highest value for the val_1 variable.

Someone linked this as answer:
[Pandas: Get N largest values and insert NaN values if there are no elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63904994/pandas-get-n-largest-values-and-insert-nan-values-if-there-are-no-elements)

However, If using that approach I need to group by label. So in that case the output would then become:

```
 label  true_id     top1_id_val_1             top2_id_val_1         top3_id_val_1
    A   2             2                          3               1
    B   4             2                          4               3
```

Anyone knows how to this?

Comment: This is really similar to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63904994/pandas-get-n-largest-values-and-insert-nan-values-if-there-are-no-elements) that got asked earlier.

Comment: there is a difference though because in this question it is per label (A, B etc.) and not for all data in one go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby` with a custom `apply` function to achieve your desired result.

```
def sorted_maximums(group, nlargest, upto=False):
    # Get the largest IDs in the current group
    largest_ids = group.nlargest(nlargest, "val_1")["ID"]
    index = ["val_1_ID_rank_{}".format(i) for i in range(1, nlargest+1)]
    
    # Drop data if we're only interested in the nlargest value
    #  and none of the IDs leading up to it
    if upto is False:
        largest_ids = largest_ids.iloc[nlargest-1:]
        index = index[-1:]
        
    # Get the ID at the max "true_val"
    true_val_max = group.at[group["true_val"].idxmax(), "ID"]
    index += ["ID_true_val_highest"]

    # Combine our IDs based on val_1 and our ID based on true_val
    data = [*largest_ids, true_val_max]
    return pd.Series(data, index=index)
    
df.groupby("label").apply(sorted_maximums, nlargest=2, upto=False).reset_index()

  label  val_1_ID_rank_2  ID_true_val_highest
0  A     3                2                  
1  B     4                4
```

```
df.groupby("label").apply(sorted_maximums, nlargest=2, upto=True).reset_index()

  label  val_1_ID_rank_1  val_1_ID_rank_2  ID_true_val_highest
0  A     2                3                2                  
1  B     2                4                4
```

Since I wasn't sure based on your question whether you were interested in getting the 2nd largest ID (@ val_1), or in getting the 1st, 2nd, AND 3rd highest ID @val_1 in one go I put in both methods. Changing upto=True will perform the latter, while upto=False will perform the former and solely get you the 1st, 2nd, OR 3rd highest ID @val_1

Answer (score 3):

You can break it into stages :

```
# grouping is relatively inexpensive :
grouping = df.groupby("label")

# get second highest val
id_val = grouping.nth(-1)["ID"].rename("ID_val_1_second_highest")

#get highest true val
# you could also do df.true_val.eq(grouping.true_val.transform('max'))
# since we know the highest is 1, I just jumped into it 
    true_val = (df.loc[df.true_val == 1, ["ID", "label"]]
               .set_index("label")
               .rename( columns={"ID": "ID_true_val_highest"}))

 # merge to get output : 
 pd.concat([id_val, true_val], axis=1,).reset_index()

    label   ID_val_1_second_highest ID_true_val_highest
0       A      3                        2
1       B      4                        4
```

Comment: Clever – I wasn't aware of the `groupby.nth` method

Answer (score 1):

After trying out a few methods (namely, sorting + ranking + melting, pivoting, groupby with custom functions), I've come to the conclusion that an expanded groupby is your best solution. (Best use for specialized cases like this one):

```py
records = []

# Iterate through your groupby objects
for group_label, group_df in df[["label","ID","val_1"]].groupby("label"):
    # get ranked indices
    rank_idx = group_df["val_1"].rank()
    # extract individual attributes
    ID_true_val_highest = group_df.loc[rank.rank_idx[1], "ID"]
    ID_val_1_second_highest = group_df.loc[rank.rank_idx[2], "ID"]

    # store your observations
    rec = {
        "label":group_label,
        "ID_true_val_highest":ID_true_val_highest,
        "ID_val_1_second_highest":ID_val_1_second_highest,
        }
    records.append(rec)
    
# make into a dataframe
pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)

    label   ID_true_val_highest ID_val_1_second_highest
0   A   2.0 3.0
1   B   2.0 4.0
```